# Dropped HDD seems to be working fine with Windows, makes clicking noise when connected to Raspberry Pi 5

Tags: hard-drive, usb, external-hard-drive, power-supply, raspberry-pi

I dropped my External HDD (WD My Passport 5TB) while unplugging it from my Windows PCs USB port. Drop height was about 1m/3ft and it fell on the floor immediately after USB was disconnected. I'm guessing the head was already in the parked position during that point since power was disconnected.

Now to the weird part:

The drive still seems to work fine on the Windows PC, S.M.A.R.T. shows no errors and says the drive is in good condition.
However when connecting the drive to a Raspberry Pi 5 8GB powered with a 3A PSU it spins up and then makes weird clicking noises. Since the drive works on Windows I assumed it's an issue with power draw, however an older identical drive (about 3 years older) works fine both on Windows and the Pi.
lsblk doesn't show the dropped drive at all, the other one is recognized.

Both drives were previously configured as a mirrored Windows Storage Space, so I haven't lost any data.

I guess if it did take some damage, Windows would also complain about it but I'm also pretty sure both drives have the same power draw since the model is identical.

So this raises a few questions:

1. Why does the drive still work on Windows but isn't recognized by the Raspberry Pi?
2. Is it possible that the newer drive draws too much power for some reason?
3. Are there additional diagnostic steps I can take to figure out what the problem is?

Comment: is it a really thick 2.5 drive? also in theory part number's more useful than serial number here. I'd say its power draw - but I'm used to the old, very anemic model 1s

Comment: Yes, they are 2.5in drives and pretty thick. Part number is WDBPKJ0050BBK-0A and identical on both drives.

Comment: Does the disk work on the Pi, in spite of the clicks?

Comment: @harrymc The dropped one doesn't show up in lsblk, the other one does.

Comment: My opinion is that the disk was damaged in a way that's only visible on the Pi, but not on Windows. I suggest replacing this disk because it seems unreliable.

Comment: Well I'm going to replace it then, I just don't get how it still works fine with windows but not on the Pi. I guess I'll find out if it was a power issue when i try the replacement drive.

Comment: Confusing when you say, “I dropped my External HDD (WD My Passport 5TB) while unplugging it from my Windows PCs USB port.” and then say “Both drives…” What do you mean? Did two drives drop? In general, if you feel unsafe go with you gut an purchase a replacement drive. Even if the dropped drive “works” you will always have doubt in your mind; better get a new drive and not worry about it.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 "however an **older identical drive** (about 3 years older) works fine both on Windows and the Pi." I dropped one of them, just mentioned the other one as a comparison.

Comment: A clicking sound isn't indicative of hardware failure, it's expected behavior - it's caused by the heads reaching the edge of the platters, resetting to the center of the platters. That being said, S.M.A.R.T data should still be viewed and posted within a code box: download [smartmontools](https://www.smartmontools.org/wiki/Download), and either open the `smartctl` terminal, executing `smartctl -a /dev/<disk>`, or install the context menu options during install, right-click on the drive in Explorer, selecting _SMART all info_. Also run a long S.M.A.R.T test via `smartctl -t long /dev/<disk>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just got another brand new drive of the same model and it also makes the same clicking noise when connected to the Raspberry Pi so it's definitely a power issue. Looking at the drives datasheet it says that power draw is 900mA which is above the Raspberry Pis max of 600mA when using a 3A PSU. The clicking noise seems to be the emergency head parking, leading me to believe that the dropped drive didn't take any damage. As I'm using them in RAID1 anyway I'm going to keep using it since there shouldn't be any risk of losing data.

I'm going to use the 5A PSU from now on and hope that resolves the issue. Otherwise a powered hub should do.

Update: All drives work fine with a powered USB hub.